# Adding "data" from new TextLoader into exisitng Pipeline (ver. 0.6)

Tags: c#, ml.net

Im trying to improve my model from ML.NET 0.5 to 0.6 and i have a question.

I Copy-paste example from [ML.NET Cookbook](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/code/MlNetCookBook.md#how-do-i-load-data-with-many-columns-from-a-csv) that says:

```
// Create a new environment for ML.NET operations. It can be used for 
exception tracking and logging, 
// as well as the source of randomness.
var env = new LocalEnvironment();

// Create the reader: define the data columns and where to find them in the 
 text file.
 var reader = TextLoader.CreateReader(env, ctx => (
    // We read the first 11 values as a single float vector.
    FeatureVector: ctx.LoadFloat(0, 10),
    // Separately, read the target variable.
    Target: ctx.LoadFloat(11)
    ),
    // Default separator is tab, but we need a comma.
    separator: ',');


// Now read the file (remember though, readers are lazy, so the actual 
reading will happen when the data is accessed).
var data = reader.Read(new MultiFileSource(dataPath));
```

So i started to implementing it into my model:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.ML.Legacy;
using Microsoft.ML.Legacy.Data;
using Microsoft.ML.Legacy.Transforms;
using Microsoft.ML.Legacy.Trainers;
using Microsoft.ML.Legacy.Models;
using Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Data;

public static PredictionModel<CancerData, CancerPrediction> Train()
    {
        var pipeline = new LearningPipeline();
        //0.6 way to upload data into model
        var env = new LocalEnvironment();
            var reader = Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Data.TextLoader.CreateReader(env, ctx => (
            FeatureVector: ctx.LoadFloat(0, 30),
            Target: ctx.LoadText(31)
                ),
            separator: ';');

        var data = reader.Read(new MultiFileSource("Cancer-Train.csv"));

        //pipeline.Add(new TextLoader("Cancer-Train.csv").CreateFrom<CancerData>(useHeader: true, separator: ';'));
        pipeline.Add(new Dictionarizer(("Diagnosis", "Label")));
        pipeline.Add(data); //dont work, i just write it to show you what i want to do

        //below the 0.5 way to load data into pipeline!
        //pipeline.Add(new ColumnConcatenator(outputColumn: "Features",
        //    "RadiusMean",
        //    "TextureMean",
        // .. and so on...
        //    "SymmetryWorst",
        //    "FractalDimensionWorst"));
        pipeline.Add(new StochasticDualCoordinateAscentBinaryClassifier());
        pipeline.Add(new PredictedLabelColumnOriginalValueConverter() { PredictedLabelColumn = "PredictedLabel" });
        PredictionModel<CancerData, CancerPrediction> model = pipeline.Train<CancerData, CancerPrediction>();

        model.WriteAsync(modelPath);
        return model;

    }
```

The question is, how to add `var data` into my exisitng `pipeline`? What i need to do, to `var data` from ver 0.6 works on 0.5 `pipeline`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `LearningPipeline` APIs are compatible with the new static typing APIs (e.g. `TextLoader.CreateReader`). The [cookbook](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/code/MlNetCookBook.md#how-do-i-train-a-regression-model) helps to show the new APIs for training and also other scenarios like using the model for predictions. [This](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/02e85cc1f276dc154c64afffe6ea6c09c44c8647/test/Microsoft.ML.StaticPipelineTesting/Training.cs#L102) test might also be helpful for binary classification.

For your code specifically, I believe the training code would look something like:

```
var env = new LocalEnvironment();
var reader = Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Data.TextLoader.CreateReader(env, ctx => (
FeatureVector: ctx.LoadFloat(0, 30),
Target: ctx.LoadBool(31)
    ),
separator: ';');

var data = reader.Read(new MultiFileSource("Cancer-Train.csv"));

BinaryClassificationContext bcc = new BinaryClassificationContext(env);

var estimator = reader.MakeNewEstimator()
    .Append(row => (
        label: row.Target,
        features: row.FeatureVector.Normalize()))
    .Append(row => (
        row.label,
        score: bcc.Trainers.Sdca(row.label, row.features)))
    .Append(row => (
        row.label,
        row.score,
        predictedLabel: row.score.predictedLabel));

var model = estimator.Fit(data);
```

Comment: I belived, that old one will be good with new one, but not a big deal. Great job guys, cookbook explain a lot of things, thanks for that!